# Design Query : Multiple microservices or just one?

Tags: java, spring, architecture, microservices, distributed-transactions

We have a requirement wherein we have to develop service(s) that will consume an inbound XML message from MQ, parse that XML message as it has the data for the outbound messages and then publishes multiple outbound messages (count be 1k to 5k) to destination/outbound queue.

Since we would be receiving multiple inbound messages from source queue and for each inbound message we will generate and publish multiple outbound messages all in 1 transaction, we have to ensure that the transaction completes in minimal time - Either we can do this all in one microservice but then if there's some slowness in cloud envs (either MQ or service) we could face timeout issues or we can create multiple microservices wherein transactions will be spanned across, we can persist the messages in DB and all.
Let me know your views

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, transactions are a good indication to determine the cut of microservices. Distributed transactions have a very high complexity and some disadvantages. Better leave a transaction inside one deployment artifact.

An alternative approach could be horizontal scaling. If you have inbound and outbound queues, it is quite possible to deploy a single service in multiple instances to handle the load.

My advice would be to start small, with one service. This can be designed as a modulith from the beginning, so it can still be split into multiple services later without much effort if there are reasons to do so.